# JavaScript Object Key is not being assigned to variable?

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to assign the value of `boxSpaces[0]` to the variable result in the function `decalreWinner()` but the assignment is not taking place.

```
function assignSpace(mark, box) {
    const image = document.createElement("img");
    const src = mark === "x" ? X_IMAGE_URL : O_IMAGE_URL;
    image.src = src;
    box.appendChild(image);
    box.removeEventListener("click", changeToX);
    const id = parseInt(box.dataset.id);
    boxSpaces[id] = mark;
}

function isGameOver() {
    const length = emptyBoxes.length;

    if (length <= 0) {
        declareWinner();
        return true;
    } else {
        false;
    }
}

function declareWinner() {
    const result = "";
    if (boxSpaces["0"] === boxSpaces["1"] && boxSpaces["1"] === boxSpaces["2"]) {
        result = boxSpaces["0"];
        console.log(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Check your console, you have an error there: `TypeError: invalid assignment to const 'result'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `const` to declare a variable and you are tring to update it which is not possible. change it to `let` or `var`

```
function declareWinner() {
  let result = ""; //change it to let or var
  if (boxSpaces["0"] === boxSpaces["1"] && boxSpaces["1"] === boxSpaces["2"]) {
    result = boxSpaces["0"];
    console.log(result);
  }

  return result;
}
```